# create array from dataframe contain tow column

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark, dataframe, explode

I have dataframe with the schema

```
    root
       |-- _id: long (nullable = true)
       |-- data: array (nullable = true)
             |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
                |    |    |-- k: string (nullable = true)
                |    |    |-- v: string (nullable = true)
       |-- c : string (nullable = true)
```

df.show(5)

```
   ---------------------------------------
   _id  |  data                                                             |c
   1    |[[key1,key2,key3,key4,key5],[value1,value2,value3,value4,value5]]  |c1
   -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   2    |[ [key1,key3,key2,key6],[value11,value31,value2,value61] ]         |c2
   -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   3    | [[key7,key1,key3,key8,key9],[value7,value1,value3,value8,value91]]|c3
   -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   4    |[key3,key2,key4,key5,key10],[value32,value23,value43,value10]]     |c4
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   5    |[[key1 ,key2,key4,key10],[value1,value23,value42,value101]]        |c1
   .
   .
   .
   .
```

I want to know if it's possible to get this result and how i must proceed

```
  _id|key1   |key2   |key3   |key4   |key5   |key6   |key7   |key8   |key9  |key10 ...
    1|value1 |value2 |value3 |value4 |value5 |       |       |       |      |
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    2|value11|value2 |value31 |      |       |value6 |       |       |     
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    3|value1 |       |value3  |      |       |       |value7 |value8 |value91|
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------    
    4|       |value23|value32|value43|       |       |       |        |value10
     ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    5|value1 |value23|       |value42|       |       |       |       |       |value101
    .
    .
```

I tried to use explode but i did'nt get a result , I tried also to construct an array from the first tow column but it seems difficult.

Comment: the output of your show-statement looks more like you have a struct of 2 arrays (keys and values in separate arrays) instead of an array of a 3-struct. Are you sure schema and show are applied to the same dataframe?

Comment: yes I edited the schema @RaphaelRoth

Answer (score 0):

You need to map this dataframe to one where each row contains data, then you can create a new dataframe with the appropriate column names

this should point you in the right direction...

```
column_names = df.select("data").collect()[0][0]
data_df = map(lambda x: x[1],df.select("data").collect())
data_par = sc.parallelize(data_df)
new_df = spark.createDataFrame(data_par, column_names, 0.1)
```

Comment: Thank you @StevenBlack for your response but it seems that you work with pyspark. I will try to undrestand the idea and try to convert it to scala code.